# Apache2 can't close connections with restart

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I'm running a Debian webserver with Apache2 and the restart command started giving me an error.

```
root@srv:~# service apache2 stop
Stopping web server: apache2.
root@srv:~# service apache2 start
Starting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

Occasionally it actually will restart without a problem but usually I have to killall -9 apache2 first. Someone on the Debian IRC had me check my active apache2 connections and it turns out they aren't quitting and dozens of them are staying open. How can I get these to eventually time out?

Comment: Have you tried using Apache's graceful restart? `service apache graceful`

Comment: What's the output of: netstat -lnp | grep :80

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lsof -i :80
```

and then kill the associated PID.